# When I try to print my LaTex PDF from a PDF viewer, it prints the source

Tags: pdf, texstudio, ubuntu, printing

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I compile the document with TexStudio, open it with Okular, Document Viewer, etc., document looks great, but when I print it from the PDF viewer I'm using (Okular, Document Viewer, etc.), it prints the markup/source text. I even tried the "Rasterize" before printing option. How is this even possible?

Comment: The devs decided against offering print functionality from the internal pdf viewer. see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/201. Just print your pdf viewer from Okular etc..

Comment: Configure your TeXstudio to use _always_ an external PDF-Viewer instead of the internal one.

Comment: you mean if you print the *pdf file* (generated from tex) from Okular, it prints the source code (tex file) instead?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Can you replicate this for the simplest possible document? `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}`? Also, it doesn't seem to me that this is a TeXstudio issue. Could you try compiling the `.tex` file (just my "Hello" document) on the terminal, and see if the resulting pdf still results in this behaviour? I don't have Okular nor evince, so I can't check.

Comment: any updates here?

Comment: yeah, my printer broke haha

Comment: @Tahlor Hmm okay, glad it's resolved. I'll vote to close the question since this is a local issue and probably won't be of much use to others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a local issue (with the printer) and probably won't be of much use to others in the future.

Comment: No that's not correct. The printer breaking is independent of the issue, I mentioned it because I haven't been able to do any further testing because it broke.